# Prevent Duplicate Append data in JavaScript and Html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have one HTML table and I don't want the value of second column to repeat in the grid.
Here is my JavaScript:

```
var $addedProductCodes = [];

function getProductData(value){

        $td_productCode=$("#sales-product-code").val();
        var index = $.inArray($td_productCode, $addedProductCodes);
        if (index >= 0) {
                alert("You already added this Product");
            } else {
                $('#test').append("<tr><td>"+ value +"</td></tr>");
                $addedProductCodes.push($td_productCode);
            }
        }
```

and Html

```
    <tbody  id="test">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="sales-product-code" name="cm_code[]" value="" class="sales-product-code"/> </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Please help me out. Help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to

```
$('#test').append("<tr><td>"+ value +"</td></tr>")
```

should be replaced with

```
$('#test tr:last').after("<tr><td>" + value + "</td></tr>").
```

I created a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/nwoebcke/jtHJL/).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a boolean variable and use it in your conditional if. If the column is added, change the value for that variable.